# How do I split y-axis disproportionally to better show data in my plot

Tags: r, plot

I have a data.frame named `final` that looks like:

```
             labels        gvs order color       f3
1            Adygei -2.3321916     1     1 353.0184
2            Basque -0.8519079     2     1 368.1515
3            French -0.9298674     3     1 365.2545
4           Italian -2.8859587     4     1 354.4481
5          Orcadian -1.4996229     5     1 350.9650
6           Russian -1.5597359     6     1 358.9736
7         Sardinian -1.4494841     7     1 355.1171
8            Tuscan -2.4279528     8     1 362.4717
9           Bedouin -3.1717421     9     2 319.3706
10            Druze -0.5058627    10     2 346.2211
11         Mozabite -2.6491331    11     2 299.5014
12      Palestinian -0.7819299    12     2 330.4576
13          Balochi -1.4095947    13     3 327.1238
14           Brahui -1.2534511    14     3 331.0927
15          Burusho  1.7958170    15     3 335.0919
16           Hazara  2.2810477    16     3 325.2444
17           Kalash -0.9258497    17     3 337.7116
18          Makrani -0.9007551    18     3 321.5726
19           Pathan  2.5543214    19     3 326.1923
20           Sindhi  2.6614486    20     3 318.7025
21            Uygur -1.2207974    21     3 322.0286
22        Cambodian  2.3706977    22     4 310.8989
23              Dai -0.9441980    23     4 305.5687
24             Daur -1.0325107    24     4 309.0984
25              Han -0.7381369    25     4 309.1198
26           Hezhen -2.7590587    26     4 296.9128
27         Japanese -0.5644325    27     4 297.9313
28             Lahu -0.8449225    28     4 307.0776
29             Miao -0.7237586    29     4 303.6593
30          Mongola -0.9452944    30     4 302.1380
31             Naxi -0.1625003    31     4 311.8019
32           Oroqen -1.2035258    32     4 308.7219
33              She -2.7758460    33     4 302.1271
34               Tu -0.7703779    34     4 307.3750
35            Tujia -1.0265275    35     4 303.5923
36             Xibo -1.1163019    36     4 295.5764
37            Yakut -3.2102686    37     4 315.0111
38               Yi -0.9614190    38     4 296.8134
39        Colombian -1.9659984    39     5 311.3134
40        Karitiana -0.9195156    40     5 300.8539
41             Maya  2.1239768    41     5 333.8995
42             Pima -3.0895998    42     5 325.3484
43            Surui -0.9377928    43     5 313.8505
44       Melanesian -1.6961014    44     6 294.5214
45           Papuan -0.7037952    45     6 286.7389
46       BantuKenya -1.9311354    46     7 152.9971
47 BantuSouthAfrica -1.8515908    47     7 133.6722
48       BiakaPygmy -1.7657017    48     7 117.5555
49         Mandenka -0.5423822    49     7 152.8525
50       MbutiPygmy -1.6244801    50     7 114.1691
51              San -0.9049735    51     7   0.0000
52           Yoruba  2.0949378    52     7 154.4460
```

I'm using the following code to make a graph

```
jpeg("F3.SCZ.Jul_22.jpg", 700,700)
final$color <- as.factor(final$color)
levels(final$color) <- c("blue","yellow3","red","pink","purple","green","orange")
plot(final$gvs, final$f3, cex=2,pch = 21, bg = as.character(final$color), xaxt="n", xlab="Genetic Values", ylab="F3", main="SCZ")
dev.off()
```

that looks like:

[image]

I would like to split the `y-axis` at 200, to have the y-values range from 0 to 200 to take up only 10% of the graph, while 200 to 400 to take up 90% of the y-axis. Is that possible?

EDIT:

Here is the data that is running into issues:

```
             labels        gvs order color         f3
1            Adygei -2.3321916     1     1 0.09862109
2            Basque -0.8519079     2     1 0.09942770
3            French -0.9298674     3     1 0.10357547
4           Italian -2.8859587     4     1 0.09960179
5          Orcadian -1.4996229     5     1 0.10244666
6           Russian -1.5597359     6     1 0.10097691
7         Sardinian -1.4494841     7     1 0.10189642
8            Tuscan -2.4279528     8     1 0.09794686
9           Bedouin -3.1717421     9     2 0.09272493
10            Druze -0.5058627    10     2 0.09682272
11         Mozabite -2.6491331    11     2 0.08563901
12      Palestinian -0.7819299    12     2 0.09331649
13          Balochi -1.4095947    13     3 0.09227273
14           Brahui -1.2534511    14     3 0.09328593
15          Burusho  1.7958170    15     3 0.09396032
16           Hazara  2.2810477    16     3 0.09342432
17           Kalash -0.9258497    17     3 0.09666599
18          Makrani -0.9007551    18     3 0.09222257
19           Pathan  2.5543214    19     3 0.09468376
20           Sindhi  2.6614486    20     3 0.09172395
21            Uygur -1.2207974    21     3 0.09140727
22        Cambodian  2.3706977    22     4 0.08655821
23              Dai -0.9441980    23     4 0.08739080
24             Daur -1.0325107    24     4 0.08656669
25              Han -0.7381369    25     4 0.08764395
26           Hezhen -2.7590587    26     4 0.08802065
27         Japanese -0.5644325    27     4 0.08810874
28             Lahu -0.8449225    28     4 0.08609791
29             Miao -0.7237586    29     4 0.08700414
30          Mongola -0.9452944    30     4 0.08921706
31             Naxi -0.1625003    31     4 0.08646436
32           Oroqen -1.2035258    32     4 0.08719536
33              She -2.7758460    33     4 0.08656100
34               Tu -0.7703779    34     4 0.08818588
35            Tujia -1.0265275    35     4 0.08737680
36             Xibo -1.1163019    36     4 0.08806230
37            Yakut -3.2102686    37     4 0.08965344
38               Yi -0.9614190    38     4 0.08593454
39        Colombian -1.9659984    39     5 0.09114697
40        Karitiana -0.9195156    40     5 0.09040477
41             Maya  2.1239768    41     5 0.09068139
42             Pima -3.0895998    42     5 0.09084750
43            Surui -0.9377928    43     5 0.08925535
44       Melanesian -1.6961014    44     6 0.08430903
45           Papuan -0.7037952    45     6 0.08272786
46       BantuKenya -1.9311354    46     7 0.04668356
47 BantuSouthAfrica -1.8515908    47     7 0.03914248
48       BiakaPygmy -1.7657017    48     7 0.03546243
49         Mandenka -0.5423822    49     7 0.04612336
50       MbutiPygmy -1.6244801    50     7 0.03098719
51              San -0.9049735    51     7 0.00000000
52           Yoruba  2.0949378    52     7 0.04561542
```

Comment: I'm doing a slightly different analysis now, though your scaling looks beautiful in my other graph!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
my_color <- as.factor(final$color)
levels(my_color) <- c("blue","yellow3","red","pink","purple","green","orange")

par(mfrow = c(1,2))

# original plot
pos <- seq(min(final$f3), max(final$f3), by = 25)  ## y-axis tick marks position.
plot(final$gvs, final$f3, cex=2, pch=21, bg = as.character(my_color),
     xaxt="n", yaxt="n", xlab="Genetic Values", ylab="F3", main="SCZ")
axis(2, at = pos, labels = pos)  ## add y-axis

# new plot
threshold <- 260  ## cut off threshold
## some rescaling
## if f3 < threshold, we take new_f3 <- 0.1 * f3
## if f3 > threshold, we take new_f3 <- f3 - 0.9 * threshold
new_f3 <- ifelse(final$f3 < threshold, 0.1 * final$f3, final$f3 - threshold * 0.9)
## we apply the same transform to `pos` to get `new_pos`
new_pos <- ifelse(pos < threshold, 0.1 * pos, pos - threshold * 0.9)

plot(final$gvs, new_f3, cex=2, pch=21, bg = as.character(my_color),
     xaxt="n", yaxt="n", xlab="Genetic Values", ylab="F3", main="SCZ")
abline(h = threshold * 0.1, lty = 3)   # threshold line
axis(2, at = new_pos, labels = pos)
```

[image]

Comment: it's no longer working when my F3 values are decimals less than 1. Do you know why that could be?

Comment: I set my threshold to 0.08 for this graph but this is what happened: http://imgur.com/a/80Zfz

Comment: I also changed the data in other ways, I was just simplifying for you so that you would have decimals. I'll reupload the data in an edit

Answer (score 2):

I would use `trans_new()` from `scales` package to transform the y-axis. This should get you close. I prefer the continuously differentiable transform (first), but you can also do a step change in scale (second). H/T to Gregor for pointing out that `pmin` and `pmax` handle vectors and are correct here.

```
setwd("C:/Users/rherron1/Desktop/")
final <- read.table("Scratch2.txt", header=TRUE)
final$id <- NULL

# default y-scale
require(ggplot2)
a <- ggplot(final, aes(gvs, f3, color=factor(color)))
a <- a + geom_point()
a

# transform y-axis
require(scales)
skew <- function(x) x^2
iskew <- function(x) x^(1/2)
skew_trans <- function() trans_new("skew", "skew", "iskew")
b <- a + coord_trans(y="skew")
b
```

[image]

```
# transform y-axis
require(scales)
sku <- function(x) pmin(x, 200) + 9*pmax(x-200, 0)
isku <- function(x) pmax((x-200)/9, 0) + pmin(x, 200)
sku_trans <- function() trans_new("sku", "sku", "isku")
c <- a + coord_trans(y="sku")
c
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you forcing the y axis upper limit to 1000? Btw, your problem with min and max is that they return single values, you need to return vectors. I think you can use `pmin` and `pmax`.

Comment: @Gregor hah! Because I have poor reading comprehension! Thanks for the pmin tip. I'll fix this when I get back to my desk.